# Combining inner join and where statements in Eloquent

Tags: php, join, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to convert the following database query to use Eloquent:

```
$orderitems = DB::table('order_items')
    ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id')
    ->where('orders.status', 1)
    ->where('order_items.sku', $sku)
    ->select('order_items.*')
    ->get();
```

I've tried the following:

```
$orderitems = Item::where('sku', $sku)
    ->with(['order' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 0);
    }])
    ->get();
```

but it seems to be bringing back more results than it should. I can see from using `DB::getQueryLog` that the `order_items` query is not joining with the orders table:

```
select * from `order_items` where `stock_code` = ? and `order_items`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Do I need to create a new relationship between orderitems and order and add the additional where into that?

Relationships:

- Order hasMany Items
- Item hasOne Order

Comment: Try this query       "SELECT order_items.* from order_items 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = order_items.order_id
WHERE 'orders.status' = 1 AND 'order_items.sku' = $sku"

Comment: Thanks, I have working query but would like it via Elqouent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use Query Scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes

In the controller:

```
$orderitems = Item::stock($sku)->paginate(10);
```

In the orderitems model:

```
public function scopeStock($query, $sku)
{
    return $query->join('orders', function ($join) {
        $join->on('orders.id', '=', 'order_items.order_id');
        $join->where('orders.status', '=', 1);
    })
    ->select('order_items.*', 'orders.order_date')
    ->where('order_items.sku', $sku);
}
```